# Sharing Data With All Views laravel

Tags: php, laravel

i am trying updating a project from laravel 5.7 to 6.x

I have a multi language website and in the footer i have sleect box to change the language so the problem is that it gives the error:

Undefined variable: language

I have check the docs and i realy don't no what i am missing!
https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/views

my footer:

```
    <select class='form-control' id="language_footer" name="language">
     foreach($language1 as $key => $value)
     <option value="{{$key}}" {{ (Session::get('language') == $key) ? 'selected' : '' }} > {{$value}}</option>
     @endforeach
    </select>
```

This is my SetDataProvider

```
public function boot()
{
  if(env('DB_DATABASE') != '') {
    if(Schema::hasTable('language'))
    $this->language();  
  }
}

public function language()
{
    $language = Language::where('status', '=', 'Active')->pluck('name', 'short_name');
    View::share('language', $language);

    $default_language = Language::where('status', '=', 'Active')->where('default', '=', '1')->limit(1)->get();
    View::share('default_language', $default_language);
    if($default_language->count() > 0) {
        Session::put('language', $default_language[0]->value);
        App::setLocale($default_language[0]->value);
    }
}
```

In the laravel 5.7 i have no problems and seems to work in laravel 6.x it says Undefined variable: language

Thnaks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

So i am dumb!!!

I have forget to declare the SetDataProvider in app.conf